# Double Exact Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose
$$0 \to A \to X \to B \to 0 $$
is exact sequence of abelian groups and
$$0 \to A \to Y \to B \to 0 $$
is exact too.

Is that true that $X \simeq Y$?

Answer (score 5):

No. If $A$ and $B$ are $Z_2$ (cyclic of order $2$) then $X$ could be
$Z_4$ and $Y$ could be $Z_2\times Z_2$.

Isomorphism classes of these extensions are classified by the elements of $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)$.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the "isomorphism classes" that are classified by $\text{Ext}^1(B,A)$ are not just isomorphism classes of $X$ and $Y$, but isomorphism classes of the short exact sequence (that is, the isomorphism $X\to Y$ is required to commute with the maps from $A$ and to $B$).